# I can't to install lubuntu on a USB drive due to a bad unsquash configuration

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, lubuntu, laptop

I have a laptop which I only use it to play [mope](http://mope.io/). Its hard disk drive of that laptop does not work anymore, I used to used it with a Ubuntu installed on a USB drive, but as that game was running slowly on Ubuntu, I decided I have to change it to Lubuntu.

I have experience installing Ubuntu on USB drives. So I followed the steps to install Lubuntu, like I did with Ubuntu:

1. I downloaded the Lubuntu iso and [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelin%C5%AD.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
2. I booted a USB Drive with Lubuntu using YUMI
3. I installed Lubuntu to my laptop in a USB drive from another USB drive.

But the third step wasn't successful: it appeared the following message:

> Instalation Failed 
>  Bad unsquash configuration 
>  The source filesystem "/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs" does not exist.

So at the end I couldn't install Lubuntu on a USB drive. How can I do so?

Edit: The version was lubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso , I didn't mention it because I thought it didn't matter.

Comment: YUMI is no longer the method to install Ubuntu to USB sticks.  If you are on Windows, use Rufus or Etcher, not YUMI, to install the ISO.  (YUMI and Multiboot haven't been updated in eons)

Comment: You didn't mention which release but did you verify the ISO? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) or probably more important check the write to media to ensure no *squashfs* errors? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) which is mentioned in the Lubuntu manual as the "*Check disc for defects*" (where disc means your cd/dvd/thumb-drive install media not hdd/ssd https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html)

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved using Rufus instead of YUMI.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)